# Webhook callback getting unexpected response 301 from Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I've created an Azure Function and hosted it in Azure. It accepts "post" and "get" requests and I can run this locally and get some log output when I either GET or POST to it.

When I host this in Azure, I can get the output the same if I do a GET or POST, which is what I expect (via postman).

I'm using a third party tool for a callback to my Azure Function URL. When this callback gets sent, I don't get any output in the Azure CLI for logs. It is using the exact same address as I was using to get my output in the portal.

The third party tool is saying its getting an `HTTP 301` response.

Why would the callback be getting an HTTP 301 when I can post/get to the same address from Postman and get a 200 back?

Function code:

```
[FunctionName("AddressNotification")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Address Callback function hit from req: {req.Host.ToString()}");

            var content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            log.LogInformation($"Request body: {content}");

            return new OkResult();
        }
```

Third party tool saying I'm getting a 301:

[image]

Comment: Are you using http or https? Can you please share postman or curl request/response?

Comment: It seems it was only accepting HTTP requests not HTTPS. When I configured the Callback URL to be the HTTPS, i was getting a 200 successful. WHy would hitting it with HTTP only cause it to be redirected? (301)

Comment: I think you mean wise versa it accepts https but redirect http right?

Comment: sorry @VovaBilyachat yes, I mean vice versa. It was only accepting HTTPS requests not HTTP. I can see that HTTP was being redirected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you have https only enabled in your function

[image]

Comment: Yip this was set on. It says it'll redirect all http traffic to https. I'm guessing this is why the callback was getting a 301 because it was redirecting them to https?

Comment: @magna_nz yes, thats the reason i ask for http/https

Comment: @magna_nz btw if it helps please accept answer :)